# In the two cases below it is possible to define the measure of Borel Stieltjes

Tags: measure-theory

[image]

Using exercise 9.S, we see that if $f$ is increasing and continuous on the right, we can define the Borel Stieltjes measure generated by $f$. But in the 9.T. Is it possible to define the Borel Stieltjes measure in items (c) and (d)? since the functions defined in each of the items are not increasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two functions $g_3$ and $g_4$ are *weakly increasing*, or *non decreasing*. This is what the text meant with just *increasing* and is sufficient for the definition of the associated Borel-Stieltjes measure.

In particular, $\mu_{g_3} = \delta_0$ and $\mu_{g_4}=\mathcal{L}^1\lfloor(0,\infty)$.

Comment: I thought the function would need to be strictly increasing.

Comment: They are if and only if the support of the associated measure is the entire real line.

Comment: Thank you for your help!